# Mysql Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 2 tables in MySql

```
Table_A { pk_A VARCHAR 150 PRIMARY KEY, random_data } ~ 9500 rows
Table_B { pk_B VARCHAR 150, more_random_data } ~ 50000 rows
```

Relationship between them is one-to-many, pk_A will be found multiple times in Table_B on col pk_B.

My problem is:

- if i enable indexing on pk_B , php/mysql CRUD works fine, but a JOIN or anyother query from command line involving both tables takes a long time
- if i disable indexing on pk_B, php/mysql CRUD becomes laggish, but a JOIN or anyother query from command line involving both tables is instantaneous

How can i improve my database performance (i could modify my pk's from varchar to int(11)) but i wondered if there are other workarounds available

Thanks

Comment: Why you using varchar as primary key?

Comment: How are you joining the tables? The PKs should always be indexed, and foreign key columns should also be indexed for faster joins.

Comment: What's the engine being used.  There are different performance considerations between MyISAM and InnoDB.

Comment: @Book of Zeus : i didn't design the database, i migrated it from mdb to sql, what you're trying to say is to replace varchar with int

Comment: @bfavaretto : inner join, and the pk's are indexed

Comment: @cristi _b: Yes, absolutely. Integer are faster, they take up less space, and more importantly they are much quicker to compare.

Comment: @Book of Zeus : this means i need to start cleaning up the mess the other guy did

Comment: @all : i guess i'll try to replace the bad varchar pk into a proper one and read on MyISAM vs InnoDB and see how it goes, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to speed up your queries.  As the many comments suggest; you always want to keep your primary keys as small as is reasonable.  A short string, say `VARCHAR(10)` won't cause you much pain, but much larger than that, you may want to use a surrogate key.  This can be made more or less transparent by making the natural key be unique, but not in the primary key.

Table_A { pk_A VARCHAR 150 PRIMARY KEY, random_data } ~ 9500 rows
Table_B { pk_B VARCHAR 150, more_random_data } ~ 50000 rows

Your schema should probably look a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_A` (
    `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `A_name` VARCHAR(150) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `Table_B` (
    `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `B_name` VARCHAR(150) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `A_id` INTEGER REFERENCES `Table_A`(`id`),
    -- other columns
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```